# combine multi fasta sequence

Tags: linux, text-processing, bioinformatics

I have this file which has many sequences up to 500 sequence
    some of these sequence has same name 
    I want to combine the replication in one

```
file 1

>1
aa
>2
cc
>3
tt
>4
atc
>2
tag
>1
gg

outfile 

>1
aagg
>2
cctag
>3
tt
>4
atc
```

Comment: How big is this Fasta file?

Comment: I have range of size from 100k byte up to 1 M byte

Comment: You're more likely to get answers if you describe the problem in terms of what needs to be done. It looks like you have a series of header lines followed by data lines, and you want to aggregate the data lines by header. Is that correct? If so, please put the new information on your question. DO NOT PUT IT HERE IN THE COMMENTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Awk script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/^>/    { header = $0 }
!/^>/   { sequence[header] = sequence[header] $0 }

END {
    for (head in sequence) {
        printf("%s\n%s\n", head, sequence[head])
    }
}
```

It will parse the complete Fasta file into memory, concatenating all sequence data that has identical headers.  At the end, it will output the data.

Note that this approach is *not good* for large Fasta files, and will certainly break completely on genome-sized files (not enough memory).  For a better approach in those cases, one could instead consider storing the parsed data into files that are concatenated at the end. I haven't looked at implementing that though.

To run the script:

```
$ awk -f ./script.awk file.fa
>1
aagg
>2
cctag
>3
tt
>4
atc
```

Comment: thanks for your help it is work as I want much appreciate

Comment: @Ali Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the
answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).